# Possible memory leak $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, memory, web

Alright so I'm making an application for a schoolproject in AngularJS. It has an $interval running for a good 90 minutes (it's pretty much used as an actual timer) and a recursive $timeout. There's another setInterval running on the index.html file which just checks the currentTime of a playing youtube video, but it's properly cancelled. Now, I looked at the timeline in Chrome after recording for a good 7 minutes and this is what it shows.

[image]

Now I have very limited knowledge on what to do with this information, but from what I've read, the JS Heap line should be more of a saw, instead with my application it's more like steps upwards until it hits a constant. Does this indicate there's some form of memory leak in my application?

This is the recursive $timeout code:

```
function startLoop(i){
            if(i >= sponsors.length) {
                startLoop(0);
                return;
            }

            sponsorsCurrentIndex = i;
            showSponsor(i);

            recursiveStart = $timeout(function () {
                startLoop(i+1);
            }, sponsors[i].length * 1000);
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't quite look like a memory leak, as it stagnates after a while. It is a common pitfall though in angular to accidentally introduce memory leaks by creating timeouts in a controller which is initialized several times - do you remove the timeout on controller $destroy?

Comment: Thing is, the controller never really gets destroyed, it's supposed to stay there the entire time. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: What happens if you use clearInterval() to clear your old timer handle before creating a new one?